# Multiple lookups to get a wordpress blog json's feed

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I am trying to get the json for a wordpress blog - but it appears it requires multiple lookups on each news element to get the image.

The json array comes back from the server, but then provides a url to do a lookup for each image. I started to write a function to get the blog json and merge it into one array object - but I am unsure now how to proceed.

here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/emodsbjz/2/

```
  buildBlogObj(data){
      let imageBlogArrayUrl = [];

      let blogJson = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          console.log(data[i]);
            let obj = {
              "label" : data[i].title.rendered,
              "body" : data[i].content.rendered,
              "image" : "placeholder.jpg"
            }//placeholder image
            imageBlogArrayUrl.push(data[i]["_links"]["wp:featuredmedia"][0]["href"]);

            blogJson.push(obj);       
      }

      blogJson = blogJson.slice(0, 4);//latest 4

      this.setState({ blogs: blogJson });
      console.log("blogJson", blogJson);


      console.log("imageBlogArrayUrl", imageBlogArrayUrl);

      let imageBlogArray = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < imageBlogArrayUrl.length; i++) {
        this.props.fetchBlogImage(imageBlogArrayUrl[i], function(resp){
          imageBlogArray.push(resp.data.source_url)
        })
      }

      console.log("imageBlogArray", imageBlogArray);

      //let that = this;
      //blogJson[i]["image"] = resp.data.source_url;
      //that.setState({ blogs: blogJson });
      //that.setState({ blogJson[i]["image"]: resp.data.source_url });
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let that = this;    
    this.props.fetchBlog(function(resp){
      that.buildBlogObj(resp.data);      
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking to get the featured image for each post?

Comment: yeah I was - correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to get the featured image URL for each blog post, you can append the `?_embed` at the end of the REST API endpoint to get the URL of each image along with the rest of the data:

```
https://www.bizzfizz.co.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

The featured image URL can be found in the `_embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url` object path.

Comment: cheers - why would they not give the image in the first place

Comment: I guess, the JSON becomes 'heavier' along with the backend DB operations required to get the related images.